# How to break recursion in Char* function? C Programming

Tags: c

I have a ternary tree, every node got id and name.

How can I return `root->name` when `root->id == id` and break the recursion?

```c
char *nameWithUsedId(Trin_Ari *root, int idNumber) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (root->id==idNumber)
        return root->name;
    nameWithUsedId(root->left,idNumber);
    nameWithUsedId(root->middle,idNumber);
    nameWithUsedId(root->right,idNumber);
}
```

Comment: "how can i return root->name when root->id=id and break the recursion" I think that is what the shown code does. Please explain how not. What you are NOT doing correctly is if the described condition is inapplicable.

Comment: Consider making a [mre] which demonstrates what you have achieved and especially how exactly your problem manifests. Please describe the symptoms of what does not work.

Comment: I think this code doesn't work and that's why he asked.. but you are right, it seems right correct but isn't :d

Answer (score 1):

```
char *nameWithUsedId(Trin_Ari *root, int idNumber) {
    if (root==NULL)
       return NULL;
    if (root->id==idNumber)
       return root->name;
    char* left = nameWithUsedId(root->left,idNumber);
    if(left != NULL) return left;
    char* mid = nameWithUsedId(root->middle,idNumber);
    if(mid != NULL) return mid;
    return nameWithUsedId(root->right,idNumber);
}
```

your base cases are correct, but you forget returns in children calls.